# Search and replace script exclusively

Tags: perl, shell, unix

Can you give a script in perl or shell to search and replace strings "windows" to "android", across only some specific folders, and strings should be replaced only in files, not in folders name?

Comment: Do you mean to rename files or do substitution in the files themselves?

Comment: The technically correct one word answer: "yes".  Break the question down to something specific.  Which task do you not know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f|xargs perl -pi -e 's/windows/android/g'
```

-type f -this will find only files and not directories.

remaining part after the pipe will search and replace windows with android in all the files returned by teh find command